# Javascript skrollr delay

Tags: javascript, skrollr

Can I delay the movement of the background after the scroll, with skrollr plugin (http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)?

I have wrote this code, for testing:

```
<body style="min-height: 400%;">
<div id="bg1" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:0 -10000px;"></div>
<div id="bg2" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:0 -8000px;"></div>
<div id="bg3" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:0 -6000px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

It works very well, but I want to delay the backgrounds movements after the scroll... It is possible?
Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code [you already have](http://whathaveyoutried.com) *(if any)*?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are asking. But if you want the background to stay constant try using `position: fixed` for that particular scroll distance and then revert it back to `position: static`